# OpenGL not drawing nearest fragment to the camera

Tags: opengl, mesh, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I have a scene with a teapot mesh in it.
I'm using a framgment shader to light it using a source of light whose value is equal to 10.

When the scene is rendered to the default framebuffer, everything seems to be fine. [image: ok]

But, if it's rendered in a custom framebuffer, the result looks like this :[image: ko]

OpenGL seems to prefer triangles defined "at the end of" the mesh.

I want the framebuffer to contain `16bits floats` so I can store values larger than `1.0`.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Probably you don't attach a depth buffer to the framebuffer.

Comment: Oh. You're probably right. I didn't think of that. I'll do it right now.

Comment: @Rabbid76, I just added and attached a depth renderBuffer to my framebuffer and now I'm not getting any result

Comment: Ok I just found out what I did wrong : I forgot to clear the depth buffer in the drawcall using `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | **GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT**);`

Comment: Possibly someone would've pointed that out, if you would've added any code to the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add a depth renderBuffer and clear it using `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

To do so, add :

```
GLuint rboDepth;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width(), height());
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
```

to your framebuffer implementation while it's bound.